# How can get components to stretch across an entire row using BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

I'm looking at the [How To Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#features) documentation, which clearly says that

> What if none of the components has a maximum width? In this case, if
>   all the components have identical X alignment, then all components are
>   made as wide as their container.

Let's assume we're adding a lot of `JButton` instances to a `JPanel`. If the maximum width of these buttons are **none** AND we invoke `setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT)` on all of these buttons - then each  of these buttons should stretch across its entire row. The documentation even illustrates this using the below picture.

[image]

I can't get this to work!

I've tried doing `setMaximumSize(null`) and `setMaximumSize(new Dimension(-1,-1))` and `setMaximumSize(new Dimension(0,0))` on the buttons but nothing gives me the described behaviour.

What excactly does the documentation mean when it says :

> What if none of the components has a maximum width?

**What is a maximum width of none?**

---

The best I've been able to produce is the below. Reading the documentation I would expect that the buttons should be able to stretch across their entire rows. I know I can use other layout managers as well for this,  but I would like to achieve this with `BoxLayout` (granted the documentation is right / I've understood the documentation right).

[image]

```
public class CustomList extends JPanel {

    private final Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

    public CustomList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            JButton b = new JButton("Button item" + i);
            //b.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
            b.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            box.add(b);
        }
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(box, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomList l = new CustomList();
        l.setSize(200, 200);
        l.setBackground(Color.red);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vertical Box");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(l, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I see that if i replace JButton with JPanel - regardless of setting maximum size or not - then each JPanel will stretch across it's entire row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buttons actually have a maximum width.

What you can do is create `JPanel` objects with `BorderLayout` in your loop, add each button to each panel (to `BorderLayout.CENTER`, which is the default anyway).

`BorderLayout.CENTER` doesn't care about the maximum size of its child `Component`, so you end up with a `JPanel` whose whole content is filled by a `JButton`.

Since the `JPanel` itself has a huge default maximum size of `new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE)` (this is width=32767,height=32767 !!) which is the default maximum size of `Component`, you will get the expected result :

```
public CustomList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JButton b = new JButton("Button item" + i);
        //b.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
        b.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.add(b);
        box.add(panel);
    }
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    add(box, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this aligns very well with what I saw when I replaced JButton with JPanel - the panels stretched across the entire row. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note : you mention that the buttons have a maximum width. That's good. But how can a component have a maximum width of none. What does the docs mean by none?

Comment: Well I guess the "none" is misleading, it should mean "not calculated", but even `JPanel` actually has a default maximum size, but it is huge and could be considered as having no maximum size . From the source code of `Component` , the default maximum size is `new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE)` , which is width=32767,height=32767 .